# Error: code file does not contain a signature from this signerid. please request a signature

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I trying to sign my blackberry small application.
 But its giving me error after signing some file and become not responding .
 Then i close signatureTool forcefully after 1 hours. 
 How to remove this error.

and i tried to sign same application using command prompt then it's giving error.
  build failed-config.xml not find.
but i checked in my application it was present.
please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I found that I was using jdk 1.7 that's why signature tool hangs.
 Then I used jdk 1.6 and now its working fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate! This solved my problem as well. The most annoying part is that Blackberry actually recommends JDK 1.7.0 but apparently don't support it.